Minikube ingress with WSL2 not able to access in Windows browser
We have minikube cluster installed on wsl2. I have deployed service with clusterIP and have exposed it using nginx ingress. I am able to open the application using curl as well as chromium browser installed on WSL2.
But I want to access the application from windows browser, how can we achieve it. I am not using Docker desktop, I have installed docker on wsl2.

While Minikube is not forwarding to the windows host then we may not access the application running in Minikube from your windows browser. In your case Minikube may be port forwarding to the WSL2 host instead of your windows host.
To resolve your issue, try setting up the port-forwarding from WSL2 to your windows host by using the following steps:

You can fetch the Minikube IP and the Minikube service command to forward the port to your windows host.
minikube service <service-name\> –url=http://<windows-host-ip\>:<port\> 

Now open the windows browser and try to access the application using: http://<windows-host-ip\>:<port\>.  Check and let me know if you are able to access your Minikube ingress through your windows browser.



what to use for windows ip , how to get it ?

minikube service kubernetes --url=http://10.150.219.6:80
Error: invalid argument "http://10.150.219.6:80" for "--url" flag: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "http://10.150.219.6:80": invalid syntax

windows IP is the IP address of your windows machine. In command prompt, use the command ipconfig and there the IPV4 address of your network adapter is your windows IP

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further

Its not working
